# TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.post(...).then(...).dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

i am new in react redux i am getting an error like as "WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.post(...).then(...).dispatch is not a function"
please help
here is the code that i am using

> API MEAN ==  http://localhost:8000/api/

**index.js**

```
import {API} from '../backend';
import axios from 'axios';
export const getdata = (todo) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post(`${API}addtodo`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        .dispatch({
            type : 'FETCH_TODO',
            payload : todo
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use dispatch in the wrong way. What you should do is

```
import {API} from '../backend';
import axios from 'axios';
export const getdata = (todo) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post(`${API}addtodo`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            dispatch({
                type : 'FETCH_TODO',
                payload : todo
            })
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

that is because doing `.dispatch()` after `.then()` would mean you are calling the dispatch method on the Promise returned by axios.